# Not able to read multiple DB connection details from config.txt file in unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to acheive below requirement from shell scripting but not getting proper output.

Requirement:
I have one main folder which consist of two sub folders and inside the sub folders I have SQL script that I need to execute in respective DB. I am giving all the DB connection details in config.txt file. Below is the folder structure

```
Main folder
  Folder1/first.sql
  Folder2/second.sql
  config.txt
```

Config.txt content

```
DB_USER:FIRST
DB_PASSWORD:password
DB_HOST:10.192.1.162
DB_PORT:1592
DB_SERVICE_NAME:abc_1

DB_USER:SECOND
DB_PASSWORD:password
DB_HOST:10.192.1.162
DB_PORT:1592
DB_SERVICE_NAME:abd_1
```

Shell script

```
    set +x
    
    #change directory to the main folder
    cd /home/Test
    
    # Loop through all config files in the main folder
    for config_file in $(find . -maxdepth 2 -name "config.txt"); do
       source "$config_file" 
    
     
    
    echo "DB_USER:$DB_USER"
    echo "DB_PASSWORD:$DB_PASSWORD"
    echo "DB_SERVICE_NAME:$DB_SERVICE_NAME"
    
    
    # Change directory to the folder containing the SQL scripts
    folder=$(dirname "$config_file")
    cd "$folder"
    
    #echo "DB_USER:$DB_USER"
    #echo "DB_PASSWORD:$DB_PASSWORD"
    #echo "DB_SERVICE_NAME:$DB_SERVICE_NAME"
    echo "Current directory: $(pwd)"
    echo "List of SQL files:"
    find . -name "*.sql"
    echo "Processing SQL files. Please wait.."
    
    # Loop through all SQL scripts in the current folder and its subfolders
    sql_files=$(find . -name "*.sql")
    if [ -n "$sql_files" ]; then
    while IFS= read -r file; do
                echo "Executing SQL script $file"
                echo "DB_USER: $DB_USER"
                echo "DB_SERVICE_NAME:$DB_SERVICE_NAME"
        sqlplus -s "$DB_USER/$DB_PASSWORD@$DB_SERVICE_NAME" < "$file" > /dev/null
                
                if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                    echo "Error executing $file"
                    exit 1
                fi
        done <<< "$sql_files"
    else
    echo "No SQL files found in the current directory"
    fi
    # Change back to the main folder
    cd ..
    done
    
    echo "All SQL scripts executed successfully for all connections"
    exit 0
```

Issue:

When I am trying to execute the above shell scripts it takes only the second DB connection details and executes the SQL script twice.

SQL script

first SQL file

```
create table test(colA number,colB number);
insert into test values(1,2);
commit;

GRANT SELECT ON FIRST.TEST TO READ_ROLE;
```

Second SQL file

```
create table test(colA number,colB number);
insert into test values(1,2);
commit;

GRANT SELECT ON SECOND.TEST TO READ_ROLE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you have stored both SQL configuration data in a single `config.txt` file with same variable names:

```
DB_USER:FIRST
DB_PASSWORD:password
DB_HOST:10.192.1.162
DB_PORT:1592
DB_SERVICE_NAME:abc_1

DB_USER:SECOND         #<------------ Same Variable DB_USER as used above
DB_PASSWORD:password   #<------------ Same Variable DB_PASSWORD as used above
DB_HOST:10.192.1.162   #<------------ Same Variable DB_HOST as used above
DB_PORT:1592           #<------------ Same Variable DB_PORT as used above
DB_SERVICE_NAME:abd_1  #<------------ Same Variable DB_SERVICE_NAME as used above
```

Upon sourcing this file as `source config.txt`, the last assigned value to the variables will get stored and will be effective, in this case the variables will always hold following values in an active shell session with this file is sourced:

```
DB_USER:SECOND
DB_PASSWORD:password
DB_HOST:10.192.1.162
DB_PORT:1592
DB_SERVICE_NAME:abd_1
```

The first assigned values to the above variables will be overwritten.

To overcome this issue, you have to store the Database variables into different files such as `config-1.txt` and `config-2.txt`.
Also, the logic should be written such that the respective configuration file should gets sourced before executing the SQL file.

To achieve that, one possibility out of many possible solution is that:
All the sql files and configuration files can be stored in two different bash arrays and depending on the array index the config file should be sourced before executing the SQL file instructions.

I have posted a modified version of your shell script:

```
    #change directory to the main folder
    cd /home/Test
    
    # Loop through all config files in the main folder
    config_files=($(find . -maxdepth 2 -name "config*.txt"))
    echo "Config Files: ${config_files[0]} and ${config_files[1]}"
    
    # Change directory to the folder containing the SQL scripts
    folder=$(dirname "$config_file")
    cd "$folder"
    
    echo "Current directory: $(pwd)"
    echo "Processing SQL files, Please wait..."
    
    # Loop through all SQL scripts in the current folder and its subfolders
    sql_files=($(find . -name "*.sql"))
    for sql_f in "${!sql_files[@]}"; do
        echo "$sql_f ==> ${sql_files[sql_f]}"
        echo "$sql_f ==> ${config_files[sql_f]}"
        source ${config_files[sql_f]}
        while IFS= read -r file; do
        echo "Executing SQL script $file"
        echo "DB_USER: $DB_USER"
        echo "DB_SERVICE_NAME:$DB_SERVICE_NAME"
        echo "sqlplus -s "$DB_USER/$DB_PASSWORD@$DB_SERVICE_NAME" < "$file" > /dev/null"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Error executing $file"
            exit 1
        fi
        done <<< "${sql_files[sql_f]}"
    done
    # Change back to the main folder
    cd ..
    echo "All SQL scripts executed successfully for all connections"
    exit 0
```

The directory structure is shown below:

```
MainFolder/
├── config-1.txt
├── config-2.txt
├── Folder1
│   └── first.sql
├── Folder2
│   └── second.sql
└── the-shell-script.sh
```

I hope this resolves your issue.

---

Update: Based on your comment:

> Thanks for responding but in real scenario I am not sure how many DB connections I need to add in config file so I want to give all the DB details in single config file and then iterate through all the sub folders to execute SQL script.

As you mentioned that, in real scenario the number of DB connections are not known.
Keeping above requirement in mind, you need to follow some constructs based on bash behavior.

1. The `config.txt` should contain all DB connections but with a different variable name e.g. `DB_USER_0=FIRST`, `DB_PASSWORD_0=password_0`, `DB_USER_1=SECOND` and so on
2. The folder containing SQL scripts `first.sql`, `second.sql` etc should be in numeric ascending order such as `Folder1/first.sql`, `Folder2/second.sql` as you mentioned in your original Question

Keeping in mind your new requirement (which you didn't mention in your Question originally) and the constraints, you can refer the following modified shell script and use it to enhance the functionality based on your further new requirements per your needs:

```
#change directory to the main folder
cd /home/Test
# Loop through all config files in the main folder
config_files=$(find . -maxdepth 2 -name "config.txt")
echo "Config Files: ${config_files}"
source ${config_files}

# Change directory to the folder containing the SQL scripts
folder=$(dirname "$config_file")
cd "$folder"

echo "Current directory: $(pwd)"
echo "Processing SQL files, Please wait..."

# Loop through all SQL scripts in the current folder and its subfolders
sql_files=($(find . -name "*.sql" | sort -n))   # find all files ending with *.sql extension and store it in array named sql_files with abs path
for sql_f in "${!sql_files[@]}"; do # iterate through all the elements of sql_files
    echo "$sql_f ==> ${sql_files[sql_f]}"
        
    while IFS= read -r file; do
        DB_USER="DB_USER_$sql_f"        #expand environment variable DB_USER_0 and so on using iterator value $sql_f
        DB_PASSWORD="DB_PASSWORD_$sql_f"
        DB_HOST="DB_HOST_$sql_f"
        DB_PORT="DB_PORT_$sql_f"
        DB_SERVICE_NAME="DB_SERVICE_NAME_$sql_f"
        
        echo "Executing SQL script $file"
        echo "DB_USER: ${!DB_USER}"
        echo "DB_SERVICE_NAME: "${!DB_SERVICE_NAME}""
        echo "sqlplus -s "${!DB_USER}/${!DB_PASSWORD}@${!DB_SERVICE_NAME}" < "$file" > /dev/null"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Error executing $file"
            exit 1
        fi
    done <<< "${sql_files[sql_f]}"
done
# Change back to the main folder
cd ..
echo "All SQL scripts executed successfully for all connections"
exit 0
```

The respective `config.txt` file should be in the following format:

```
DB_USER_0=ZERO
DB_PASSWORD_0=password_0
DB_HOST_0=10.192.1.162
DB_PORT_0=1592
DB_SERVICE_NAME_0=abc_0

DB_USER_1=FIRST
DB_PASSWORD_1=password_1
DB_HOST_1=10.192.1.162
DB_PORT_1=1592
DB_SERVICE_NAME_1=abc_1


DB_USER_2=SECOND
DB_PASSWORD_2=password_2
DB_HOST_2=10.192.1.162
DB_PORT_2=1592
DB_SERVICE_NAME_2=abc_2
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but in real scenario I am not sure how many DB connections I need to add in config file so I want to give all the DB details in single config file and then iterate through all the sub folders to execute SQL script.

Comment: Just need one clarification as I am providing DB connections passwords in my config file, is there any way to encrypt the password and decrypt while executing the SQL scripts or if you have encountered such scenarios in real time that you can guide me?

Comment: You can ask a new question on encrypting the passwords